# file not found error while viewing pdftext

Tags: texmaker

`\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}`
i have just started to learn LaTeX in ubuntu by TeXmaker..
I was going through a beginners tutorial and I tried following...[image: so it is showing the following error]

I am very new to this .can someone tell me about a good reference to  learn latex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a Minimal Working Example [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for see your code and then can help you.

If you're starting in LaTeX, this is [a good choice](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort-english).

Comment: Have you run e.g. PDFLaTeX (shortcut F6) on the file? You need to do that before you can View PDF.

Comment: Thanx,it worked..